# All HTML Tags supported by a Browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Using JavaScript, is it possible to obtain a list of the tags that a browser supports?

Comment: what would that be used for?

Comment: @programminginallston To fix the OPs curiosity.  Hopefully the OP isn't a cat...

Comment: I don't see a valid use case for this. Can you explain what it is you hope to accomplish?

Comment: @cale_b That is not correct, CSS is irrelevant.

Comment: I suppose you can make them behave display-wise, but can not necessarily utilize them fully via js - is that the difference @WesleyMurch?

Comment: code checking for supported tags would probably start with: `if (IE) return false`

Comment: @cale_b Something like that, however I'm nearly certain you cannot style unknown elements either in IE<9.

Comment: @WesleyMurch You can absolutely style unknown elements.  We were rolling HTML5 sites long before IE10 came out.

Comment: @cale_b Using this? https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/

Comment: @WesleyMurch - hmm.  Now that you mention it, yes.  So javascript to the rescue on that!  Thanks!

Comment: @cale_b Basically you just need to run `document.createElement('foo');` and it will be style-able.

Comment: What do you mean by 'support'? Do you want to know which tags (including non-standard) have special meaning for the particular browser, or which tags from the particular spec are implemented completely (in DOM interface, behavior etc.)?

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn By "support" I mean a browser recognize and render appropriate.

Comment: @dc5 No, I am not a cat...sometimes I wish I was, but not today XD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a decent idea of what is supported by introspection on the window.

Try this out:

```
props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)
for (var idx in props) {
  if (props[idx].indexOf("HTML") == 0) {
    //do something here
    console.log(props[idx]);
  }  
}
```

This is in no way exhaustive as far as I know but it will tell you in most browsers what tags have a DOM object type.

Here is sample output by running this in my Chrome console:

```
HTMLUnknownElement
HTMLOptionsCollection
HTMLFormControlsCollection
HTMLAllCollection
HTMLCollection
HTMLUListElement
HTMLTitleElement
HTMLTextAreaElement
HTMLTemplateElement
HTMLTableSectionElement
HTMLTableRowElement
HTMLTableElement
HTMLTableColElement
HTMLTableCellElement
HTMLTableCaptionElement
HTMLStyleElement
HTMLSpanElement
HTMLSelectElement
HTMLScriptElement
HTMLQuoteElement
HTMLProgressElement
HTMLPreElement
HTMLParamElement
HTMLParagraphElement
HTMLOutputElement
HTMLOptionElement
HTMLOptGroupElement
HTMLObjectElement
HTMLOListElement
HTMLModElement
HTMLMeterElement
HTMLMetaElement
HTMLMenuElement
HTMLMarqueeElement
HTMLMapElement
HTMLLinkElement
HTMLLegendElement
HTMLLabelElement
HTMLLIElement
HTMLKeygenElement
HTMLInputElement
HTMLImageElement
HTMLIFrameElement
HTMLHtmlElement
HTMLHeadingElement
HTMLHeadElement
HTMLHRElement
HTMLFrameSetElement
HTMLFrameElement
HTMLFormElement
HTMLFontElement
HTMLFieldSetElement
HTMLEmbedElement
HTMLDivElement
HTMLDirectoryElement
HTMLDataListElement
HTMLDListElement
HTMLCanvasElement
HTMLButtonElement
HTMLBodyElement
HTMLBaseElement
HTMLBRElement
HTMLAreaElement
HTMLAppletElement
HTMLAnchorElement
HTMLElement
HTMLDocument
```

Comment: This is interesting, but it gives a list of interfaces, not a list of element types. For example, the list does not contain anything corresponding to `strong` or `span`, because these elements do not have interfaces of their own (they just use the generic HTMLElement interface).

Comment: For what I can see, there is probably not a reliable way to do it, but I like this method because it can be used without a starting list and, as @JukkaK.Korpela says, there will be holes in the list, it is still a pretty cool method.

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to start with a known list of candidate tags, you could try something like this:

```
document.createElement("asdf") instanceof HTMLUnknownElement
true
document.createElement("canvas") instanceof HTMLUnknownElement
false
```

If you need to support IE8, you could use this approach:

```
function browserSupports(elementTagName) {
    var el = document.createElement(elementTagName);
    return !((el instanceOf HTMLUnknownElement) || (el instanceof HTMLGenericElement));
}
```

Here's another approach that doesn't rely on specific named constructors.

```
function browserSupports(elementTagName) {
    var unknownel = document.createElement("zzxcv");
    var el = document.createElement(elementTagName);
    return unknownel.constructor !== el.constructor;
}
```

It still doesn't seem to work in IE8 though.

Comment: This isn’t robust at all, since old browsers don’t recognize `HTMLUnknownElement`. And testing this way with IE 10 in IE 8 mode, I get the result `false` if I test support for *any* element (including elements that are surely supported, like `p`).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela:  Good point.  I've added a new implementation that handles IE8.

Comment: My original idea was to not use a list tags to start but this is also a pretty cool approach =).

Answer (score 5):

Every JavaScript *html* element object, created by **document.createElement()**, has a constructor function which always starts with "HTML..." and ends with "...Element". All these are inherit from HTMLElement. Each of these are reachable in the **window** object via *Object.getOwnPropertyNames()*.

So you can get all valid tag names by iterate over all property names in window and filter them with *HTML...ELement*:

```
function getAllTagNames()
{
    let names = [];

    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).forEach(name =>
    {
        if(name.startsWith('HTML') && name.endsWith('Element') && Object.getPrototypeOf(window[name]) == HTMLElement)
        {
            names.push(name.substr(4, name.length - 11).toLowerCase());
        }
    });

    names.sort((left, right) =>
    {
        if(left.toLowerCase) { left = left.toLowerCase(); }
        if(right.toLowerCase) { right = right.toLowerCase(); }

        return left == right ? 0 : (left < right ? -1 : 1);
    });

    return names;
}
```

**How to use it:**

```
console.log(getAllTagNames()); // [anchor", "area", "base", "body", "br", ...]
```

**edit**

Some constructor functions for html elements are just base constructor functions (for example *HTMLMediaElement*).
In this case the base constructor function of *HTMLAudioElement* (**<audio></audio>**) and *HTMLVideoElement* (**<video></video>**) are not directly inherit from *HTMLElement*.
So it's necessary to run through the complete protype chain, the **instanceof** operator is suitable for this:

```
window['HTMLAudioElement'].prototype instanceof HTMLElement
```

Another aspect is that some constructor function names fit not to the equivalent html tag name (<*a*> => HTML*Anchor*Element) and some other names fit to several tags (for example **<h1></h1>, <h2></h2>, <h3></h3>, <h4></h4>, <h5></h5>, <h6></h6>**) with the same constructor function. [> see mdn.](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLHeadingElement)

Currently there is no other way in JavScript to create the wrong identified tag name with document.createElement(tagName);, check whether the constructor is an HTMLUnknownElement and fixed these manually:

```
function getAllTagNames()
{
    let items = [];

    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).forEach(name =>
    {
        if(name.startsWith('HTML') && name.endsWith('Element') && window[name].prototype instanceof HTMLElement)
        {
            items.push({ constructorName: name, tagName: name.substr(4, name.length - 11).toLowerCase() });
        }
    });

    items.sort((leftItem, rightItem) =>
    {
        let left = leftItem.tagName;
        let right = rightItem.tagName;

        if(left.toLowerCase) { left = left.toLowerCase(); }
        if(right.toLowerCase) { right = right.toLowerCase(); }

        return left == right ? 0 : (left < right ? -1 : 1);
    });

    function insertSorted(item)
    {
        let index = 0;
        while(item.tagName > items[index].tagName) { index++; }
        items.splice(index, 0, item);
    }

    let disagreements = [];
    items = items.filter(item =>
    {
        let tagName = item.tagName;

        switch(tagName) // deprecated
        {
            case "keygen": return false;
        }

        let filter = tagName == "unknown" || document.createElement(tagName).constructor == HTMLUnknownElement;
        if(filter && tagName != "unknown") { disagreements.push(item); }

        return !filter;
    });

    disagreements = disagreements.filter(item =>
    {
        switch(item.tagName) // base constructor
        {
            case "media": return false;
        }

        return true;
    });

    disagreements.forEach(item => 
    {
        let tagName = item.tagName;

        function exchange(tagName)
        {
            insertSorted({ constructorName: item.constructorName, tagName: tagName });
        }

        switch(tagName)
        {
            case 'anchor':
                exchange('a');
                break;

            case 'directory':
                exchange('dir');
                break;

            case 'dlist':
                exchange('dl');
                break;

            case 'heading':
                exchange('h1');
                exchange('h2');
                exchange('h3');
                exchange('h4');
                exchange('h5');
                exchange('h6');
                break;

            case 'image':
                exchange('img');
                break;

            case 'mod':
                exchange('del');
                exchange('ins');
                break;

            case 'olist':
                exchange('ol');
                break;

            case 'paragraph':
                exchange('p');
                break;

            case 'quote':
                exchange('blockquote');
                exchange('q');
                break;

            case 'tablecaption':
                exchange('caption');
                break;

            case 'tablecell':
                exchange('th');
                exchange('td');
                break;

            case 'tablecol':
                exchange('col');
                exchange('colgroup');
                break;

            case 'tablerow':
                exchange('tr');
                break;

            case 'tablesection':
                exchange('tfoot');
                exchange('thead');
                exchange('tbody');
                break;

            case 'ulist':
                exchange('ul');
                break;

            default:
                console.log('disagree', tagName);
                if(console.warn && tagName != "") { console.warn("unknown tag name for " + item.constructorName); }
                break;
        }
    });

    return items.map(item => item.tagName);
}
```

**edit 2:**

```
let tagNames =
[
    { name: "a", constr: "HTMLAnchorElement" },
    { name: "area", constr: "HTMLAreaElement" },
    { name: "audio", constr: "HTMLAudioElement" },
    { name: "base", constr: "HTMLBaseElement" },
    { name: "body", constr: "HTMLBodyElement" },
    { name: "br", constr: "HTMLBRElement" },
    { name: "button", constr: "HTMLButtonElement" },
    { name: "canvas", constr: "HTMLCanvasElement" },
    { name: "content", constr: "HTMLContentElement" },
    { name: "data", constr: "HTMLDataElement" },
    { name: "datalist", constr: "HTMLDataListElement" },
    { name: "details", constr: "HTMLDetailsElement" },
    { name: "dialog", constr: "HTMLDialogElement" },
    { name: "dir", constr: "HTMLDirectoryElement" },
    { name: "div", constr: "HTMLDivElement" },
    { name: "dl", constr: "HTMLDListElement" },
    { name: "embed", constr: "HTMLEmbedElement" },
    { name: "fieldset", constr: "HTMLFieldSetElement" },
    { name: "font", constr: "HTMLFontElement" },
    { name: "form", constr: "HTMLFormElement" },
    { name: "frame", constr: "HTMLFrameElement" },
    { name: "frameset", constr: "HTMLFrameSetElement" },
    { name: "head", constr: "HTMLHeadElement" },
    { name: "h1", constr: "HTMLHeadingElement" },
    { name: "h2", constr: "HTMLHeadingElement" },
    { name: "h3", constr: "HTMLHeadingElement" },
    { name: "h4", constr: "HTMLHeadingElement" },
    { name: "h5", constr: "HTMLHeadingElement" },
    { name: "h6", constr: "HTMLHeadingElement" },
    { name: "hr", constr: "HTMLHRElement" },
    { name: "html", constr: "HTMLHtmlElement" },
    { name: "iframe", constr: "HTMLIFrameElement" },
    { name: "img", constr: "HTMLImageElement" },
    { name: "input", constr: "HTMLInputElement" },
    { name: "label", constr: "HTMLLabelElement" },
    { name: "legend", constr: "HTMLLegendElement" },
    { name: "li", constr: "HTMLLIElement" },
    { name: "link", constr: "HTMLLinkElement" },
    { name: "map", constr: "HTMLMapElement" },
    { name: "marquee", constr: "HTMLMarqueeElement" },
    { name: "menu", constr: "HTMLMenuElement" },
    { name: "meta", constr: "HTMLMetaElement" },
    { name: "meter", constr: "HTMLMeterElement" },
    { name: "del", constr: "HTMLModElement" },
    { name: "ins", constr: "HTMLModElement" },
    { name: "object", constr: "HTMLObjectElement" },
    { name: "ol", constr: "HTMLOListElement" },
    { name: "optgroup", constr: "HTMLOptGroupElement" },
    { name: "option", constr: "HTMLOptionElement" },
    { name: "output", constr: "HTMLOutputElement" },
    { name: "p", constr: "HTMLParagraphElement" },
    { name: "param", constr: "HTMLParamElement" },
    { name: "picture", constr: "HTMLPictureElement" },
    { name: "pre", constr: "HTMLPreElement" },
    { name: "progress", constr: "HTMLProgressElement" },
    { name: "q", constr: "HTMLQuoteElement" },
    { name: "script", constr: "HTMLScriptElement" },
    { name: "select", constr: "HTMLSelectElement" },
    { name: "shadow", constr: "HTMLShadowElement" },
    { name: "slot", constr: "HTMLSlotElement" },
    { name: "source", constr: "HTMLSourceElement" },
    { name: "span", constr: "HTMLSpanElement" },
    { name: "style", constr: "HTMLStyleElement" },
    { name: "td", constr: "HTMLTableCellElement" },
    { name: "th", constr: "HTMLTableCellElement" },
    { name: "col", constr: "HTMLTableColElement" },
    { name: "colgroup", constr: "HTMLTableColElement" },
    { name: "table", constr: "HTMLTableElement" },
    { name: "tr", constr: "HTMLTableRowElement" },
    { name: "tbody", constr: "HTMLTableSectionElement" },
    { name: "tfoot", constr: "HTMLTableSectionElement" },
    { name: "thead", constr: "HTMLTableSectionElement" },
    { name: "template", constr: "HTMLTemplateElement" },
    { name: "time", constr: "HTMLTimeElement" },
    { name: "title", constr: "HTMLTitleElement" },
    { name: "track", constr: "HTMLTrackElement" },
    { name: "ul", constr: "HTMLUListElement" },
    { name: "video", constr: "HTMLVideoElement" }
];
```

Comment: Pretty cool. There are a very large number of missing elements though. Just in the A, B, and Cs, there's aside, abbr, address, article, b, bdi, bdo, blockquote, caption, cite, code, col, colgroup. This could be a good method of doing things if combined with just manually adding the rest of the missing elements. What a pain...

Comment: Thanx a lot. This really helped my hobby project. If you have any new way of generating a newer list as you had in "Edit 2", let me know!
Right now the <shadow> and <content> is deprecated and is no longer supported by the browsers. There might be new tags and constructors that are not in there.

Comment: For example, I noticed that these tags are not in that list: header, footer, section, article

Answer (score 3):

There is no general way but each element has specific way to see if it's supported

Canvas element support:

```
var canvasSupported = "getContext" in document.createElement("canvas");
```

Input type support:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "color"
var colorInputSupported = input.type === "color";
//The above relies on the fact that type is enumerated and 
//falls back to "text" with invalid value
//The technique doesn't necessarily carry over to other properties
```

Audio element support:

```
var audioElementSupported = "play" in document.createElement("audio");
```

Progress element support

```
var progressElementSupported = "max" in document.createElement("progress");
```

Comment: This is indeed element-specific. For example, the technique used for `input` type support fails if you try to apply it to testing support to `align=char` for `td` (the result is true, even though no browser actually supports this value).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Yeah I didn't mean to imply that the `input` type testing technique carries over to anything else. It specifically works because `type` is an enumerated attribute. I have clarified this in an edit.

Comment: The `align` attribute is enumerated, too. Even attributes that are formally similar (with an enumated list of values) may be treated differently by a browser.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I didn't find anything about it except it being deprecated