# JS—List of all registered Elements

Tags: javascript, element

I am looking for a way to get a list of all the elements (nodeNames) supported/registered at the client.

In other words: There are `<a>, <b>, <caption>, <div>, …` and a lot more well known HTML elements one can create and use. With `document.registerElement` one can add more.

As the title says, I am looking for a way to get all the elements (at least their names), currently registered. Some dummy code could look like this:

```
var list = document.listRegisteredElements();

//yielding ['a', 'body',  … , 'div', 'i', 'my-registered-element', …];
```

Thanks so far!

Comment: [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("*")).map(function(a){return a.tagName;}).filter(function(a,b,c){return c.indexOf(a)==b;}).sort(); will show all in-use...

Comment: you can wrap and replace document.registerElement() to push its first (or all) arguments into a reachable array...

Comment: @dandavis -- very cool approach!! But it actually displays the elements in use, only. I am looking for a way to get a list of elements which are possible, too. F.I. On a page without any `<a>`, »a« ahould be included in the list…

Comment: apply my 2nd comment before any of the custom elements are defined, and use a hard-coded list of spec-approved tags. i don't know of any way to reveal all "known" tags via an API reachable by JS. other than by randomly generating strings, creating them, and seeing if the constructor is unknown; something you don't want to do...

Comment: @philipp You can take all predefined elements from HTML5 spec and add what was added using dandavis' approach.

Comment: ok… ok… I have had read the second comment before writing my first. I justr thought that is another way, than using the predefinied elements and catching the newly registered ones. All in, the API I am looking does not seem to exist.

Comment: Related: [All HTML Tags supported by a Browser](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18220181/1529630)