# HTML element tag name from constructor

Tags: javascript, html, constructor

Consider the function:

```
tagName => document.createElement(tagName).constructor
```

which returns the constructor function of HTML elements with a particular tag name.

I would like to reverse this process and get the tag name (or names?) of an HTML element provided its constructor. I would like to do this for some unit tests that I'm writing, but there are probably other use cases.

A few examples:

```
tagNameOf(HTMLDivElement)       // should be "div"
tagNameOf(HTMLIFrameElement)    // should be "iframe"
tagNameOf(HTMLHtmlElement)      // should be "html"
tagNameOf(HTMLTableRowElement)  // should be "tr"
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea where to start from, except maybe using a static mapping.

Is there a simple method to achieve this?

Comment: Why not just access the `tagName` property of the passed element?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Well, I don't have an element to start with, just a constructor.

Comment: Oh, I see, I thought `tagNameOf(HTMLDivElement)` meant there was an actual element

Comment: I think this question is sort of relevant if someone wants more info about this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220181/all-html-tags-supported-by-a-browser

Answer (score 2):

I suppose a dirty-looking solution would be to check the constructor's `toString()`:

```js
const makeConstructor = tagName => document.createElement(tagName).constructor;
const constructorToTagName = constr => constr.toString().match(/HTML(\w+)Element/)[1].toLowerCase();
console.log(constructorToTagName(makeConstructor('div')));
console.log(constructorToTagName(makeConstructor('span')));
```

Comment: Yes this is in fact what I was looking for, not so dirty after all. You could also use `constr.name` instead of `constr.toString()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for elements like `<a>` or `<tr>`. I've added an example to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I extracted this solution of one of my projects:

```js
const tagNameOf = (function () {
  // This lookuptable is key to the solution, it must somehow be kept up to date
  const elementNameLookupTable = {
    'UList': ['ul'],
    'TableCaption': ['caption'],
    'TableCell': ['th', 'td'],
    'TableCol': ['col', 'colgroup'],
    'TableRow': ['tr'],
    'TableSection': ['thead', 'tbody', 'tfoot'],
    'Quote': ['q'],
    'Paragraph': ['p'],
    'OList': ['ol'],
    'Mod': ['ins', 'del'],
    'Media': ['video', 'audio'],
    'Image': ['img'],
    'Heading': ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6'],
    'Directory': ['dir'],
    'DList': ['dl'],
    'Anchor': ['a']
  };
  return function (HTMLElementConstructor) {
    let match; let tagName = [];
    if (typeof HTMLElementConstructor === 'function') {
      match = /HTML(\w+)Element/.exec(HTMLElementConstructor.name);
      if (match) {
        tagName = elementNameLookupTable[match[1]] || [match[1].toLowerCase()];
      }
    }
    return tagName;
  };
}());

// Test:
console.log(tagNameOf(HTMLAnchorElement));
console.log(tagNameOf(HTMLMediaElement));
console.log(tagNameOf(HTMLHeadingElement));
```

It has to be noted that the function returns an array, since there are more than one possible corresponding tag names.